# Card Layout refreshing/updating cards

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, refresh, cardlayout

I have a jFrame witch contains displayPanel and buttonPanel.
In the button pannel, there are 2 buttons (button1, button2).
When i press button1 - a new panel (card1) shows in the displayPanel. Card1 has a textfield and that writes the value to a database.
When i press button2 - a new panel (card2) shows in the displayPanel. Card2 has a combobox that shows all those values from database.

My problem - when i click on button1, submit my value, press button2 - combobox doesn't have that value shown yet. It only shows if i close my application and run it again.

How do i make it so each time i press 'button2' (from buttonPanel in jFrame), values in combobox are refreshed?

Here is the code from jFrame, that is responsible for showing cards:

```
 private void button1ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     
       CardLayout card = (CardLayout) displayPanel.getLayout();
       card.show(displayPanel, "card1");
}

 private void button2ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     
       CardLayout card = (CardLayout) displayPanel.getLayout();
       card.show(displayPanel, "card2");
}
```

Here is the code that gets the values from database and puts them into combobox in card2:

```
public void fillComboBox(){    
    try {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rs.next()){
    String user_name= rs.getString("user_name");
    pirmaspanelsvarbumoComboBox.addItem(user_name);
   }  
    } catch (Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call your fillComboBox method when your second button is pressed.

Comment: fillComboBox method is in card2. In card2 there is a button, if i pass fillComboBox(); to that button, my combobox gets refreshed but it also doubles all other values.

can i somehow call fillComboBox method in my jFrame button2 ?

Comment: use pirmaspanelsvarbumoComboBox.removeAllItems() at the begining of your fillComboBox() method. That way, each time you call it, it will fill all your data in your empty combo box and prevent the double records.

Comment: Hmm still doubles all the data in there each time i press a button :(

Comment: Thank you, It works! just needed to write pirmaspanelsvarbumoComboBox.removeAllItems() right after the try {